# Data Migration Tool - Messes up Products on Frontend 1.9.2.4 to 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database, data-migration

I'm trying to migrate the customers and orders only from **1.9.2.4 to 2.2.4 for Magento**.

I have edited the **config.xml** and the **map.xml**. However, whenever I run the migration the products in my 2.2.4 are all messed up and no longer show on the front end even though they are still in the backend.

I have edited the **config.xml** so it only runs these steps for data migration.

```
<steps mode="data">
    <step title="Data Integrity Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
    </step>
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="PostProcessing Step">
        <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
    </step>
</steps>
```

And for the **map.xml** I added the following -

```
<ignore>
    <document>catalog_*</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <document>cms_block</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <document>cms_block_store</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <document>cms_page</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <document>cms_page_store</document>
</ignore>
```

Any idea as to why the products are affected by this migration setup?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I had to add some more to the map.xml the above is the source and the bottom is the destination.

```
<document_rules>
    <ignore>
        <document>eav*</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>wordpress_association</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>wordpress_association_type</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>cls_paypal_customer_stored</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>eltrino_region_entity</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>imaclean</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>recommender_product_link</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>smtppro_email_log</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>catalog*</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>cms_block</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>cms_block_store</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>cms_page</document>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <document>cms_page_store</document>
    </ignore>
...
</document_rules>
```

I also had to ignore all the new tables and fields in the new database.

```
<destination>
    <document_rules>
        <ignore>
            <document>magefan_blog_*</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>mageplaza*</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>signifyd_connect_case</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>signifyd_connect_retries</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>sw_dailydeals_dailydeal</document>
        </ignore>>
        <ignore>
            <document>catalog_product_index_price*</document>
        </ignore>
    ...
    </document_rules>
```

and

```
<ignore>
    <field>cms_page.page_layout</field>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <field>sales_order.fraudlabspro_response</field>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <field>sales_order.signifyd_score</field>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <field>sales_order.signifyd_guarantee</field>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <field>sales_order.signifyd_code</field>
</ignore>
```